# Java getText JTextField

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextarea

I know its easy but I am freaking doing it for about 2 hours now and I can't seems figure out why I can't pass the `JTextArea` value from a variable to the other java files because I separated my `ActionEvent` code to another File from my Object (specifically the `JTextArea`), guys find out what went wrong on my code.

`actionlistener` code:

```
public class ButtonAction{
    public static class AddInv implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        AbstractButton inv = (AbstractButton)e.getSource();
        AddInventory addInv = new AddInventory();

        if(inv.getActionCommand().equals("SAVE")){
            invName = addInv.areaName.getText();                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, invName);
        }   
    }
}
}
```

Here's my Button and textarea object code from another java file, this is my class `AddInventory`:

```
ActionListener add = new ButtonAction.AddInv();
areaName = new JTextArea(2, 35);
//my TextArea
JButton buttonSave = new JButton("SAVE");
buttonSave.addActionListener(add);
```

Guys can you try this code and tell me if it is working in your computer guys.
because what I'm planning to do is save this text area value to my database.

I'm already connected the oracle database and I just need to insert some records.

Comment: *"tell me if it is working in your computer"*  Those code snippets do not compile in my computer.  Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"tnx guys"* Your thanks can be better expressed in making the question easy to read.  A question is harder to read when it includes text-message style abbreviations like  'tnx'.  In future, please spell words properly.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ah, I'm screwed, I'm a programmer, I don't do spelling ;) (point is valid, just couldn't resist)

Comment: @Mad *"I'm screwed, I'm a programmer, I don't do spelling"*  I'm lucky, I live in **3rd** millennium, I don't do spelling - *I have a spell checker do it for me.*  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by examining the purpose of

```
addInv = new AddInventory();
s1 = addInv.areaName.getText();
```

To me, this says, create me a new `AddInventory` and give me the default value of it's `areaName` text field...which is probably nothing...

**UPDATE**

Still the same problem...

```
AddInventory addInv = new AddInventory();

if(inv.getActionCommand().equals("SAVE")){
    invName = addInv.areaName.getText();                
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, invName);
}
```

Some how, you either need to pass the reference to the text area to the action...

**UPDATE EXAMPLE**

Ideally you want some kind of controller/model to take care of this, but as an example...

```
areaName = new JTextArea(2, 35);
ActionListener add = new ButtonAction.AddInv(areaName);
//my TextArea
JButton buttonSave = new JButton("SAVE");
buttonSave.addActionListener(add);
```

And you action class...

```
public class ButtonAction{
    public static class AddInv implements ActionListener{
        private JTextArea text;
        public AddInv(JTextArea text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            AbstractButton inv = (AbstractButton)e.getSource();

            if(inv.getActionCommand().equals("SAVE")){
                invName = text.getText();                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, invName);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wait I'm sorry but it supposed to be erased, wait i just edit the code.

Comment: invName is a String so I just pass the JtextArea value to the String invName but when the JOptionPane show there nothing in there it's null.

Comment: How I mean the user shall or will be the one to input and once the button is click it should be passed to the variable, why null value is passed, As far as i know it will have a value once the user click the button so it will not be null value.

Comment: You have a reference problem. The instance of `AddInventory` that you are trying to get the value from isn't the same as the one that user used to enter data in...hence the reason the value you are getting is `null` or empty...

Comment: OK, now I get you point, how can I get the value if can't referenced it?

Comment: should I have to save it to another String variable then pass the string variable to the actionlistener class and use it?

Comment: In Swing we have this concept of Model/Control/View, where the data is separated from how it's displayed and how thew view is controlled.  Rather then using a direct reference to the field, the field would update a model. You would then use the contents of the model to update the database. It means if any one part of the chain changes, it's less likely to have an effect on other parts...

Comment: last question where can I get a tutorial on MVC(Model View Control), Thanks a lot, I loved this forum, and how can I flag this as answered question?

Comment: Have a read through [A Swing Architecture Overview](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/) and [Java SE Application Design With MVC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) for some info ;)

Comment: @Jerome Check my previous comment. I think you need to wait 15 minutes before the little check mark becomes available ;)

Comment: @Jerome: Also, don't neglect to up-vote answers you found helpful.